# Keystone.JS render multiple template files

Tags: keystonejs

I use keystone.js together with handlebars as template engine. Until now I had one .hbs-file for each page. However, HTML-Code is growing over time and I would like to split the HTML into several files. Does keystone.js offer a simple way to render multiple template files?

I'd prefer not to use technologies like webpack just for that "simple" task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use partials to break up your templates, so you can include one **.hbs** file in another file.

Add a new file in the *templates/views/partials* directory, for example **myPartial.hbs**, and then you can include it in another file like so:

```
{{> myPartial }}
```

KeystoneJS will handle registration of **.hbs** files in the *templates/views/partials* directory.

You can read more here:
http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html

If you use the KeystoneJS generator to set up your project, you can see this in action where **pagination.hbs** is included in **blog.hbs**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have an additional question before I accept your answer:
Where do I register the partials? The documentation of handlebars clearly says that I have to register this partial. I can not find the registration process for the pagination example.

Comment: You should be able to just put your partials in the **partials** directory and Keystone will handle it.

Comment: Thank you! I'll open another question for how to make multiple partial folders!